# Is there a typo on this definition?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation, viscosity-solutions

This is from Iishi's User's guide to viscosity solution.

I don't understand the $\ni$ in the definition 2.6 at the end of its first line, is it a typo?

[User's guide page 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSz6b.png)

Comment: I have the uncomfortable feeling it stands for "such that".

Comment: Not that I understood any of that, but its probably just the converse of $\in$. Meaning $x \in y$ iff $y \ni x$.

Comment: @user18921 nah that doesn't really make sense, hence i asked this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel alluded to in the comments, it means "such that." But this used to be very common, and it's actually been used to mean "such that" for over 100 years now.

You can see it listed in [Common Math Symbols](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~anne/WQ2007/mat67-Common_Math_Symbols.pdf), for example.

Comment: indeed, this made most sense, when you read the thing too, I wanted to be sure.